# Using cycle-onionify within a non-onionified Cycle.js app

Tags: javascript, typescript, cyclejs

I may be attempting something foolish, but I have a sufficiently-large *non*-onionified Cycle.js app and I’m trying to learn how [onionify](https://github.com/staltz/cycle-onionify) works, so I’d like to embed an onionified component into my original non-onion app.

So I have a simple onion-ready component, the [increment/decrement example](https://github.com/staltz/cycle-onionify/blob/master/examples/basic/src/main.js), and I have a simple non-onion Cycle app, the [“Hello Last Name”](https://github.com/cyclejs/cyclejs/blob/master/examples/hello-lastname/src/index.ts) example—how do I smoosh the two together so I have the incrementer component and the Hello component one after the other in the same webpage?

### `Counter.ts`, onion-ready component

```
import xs from 'xstream';
import run from '@cycle/run';
import { div, button, p, makeDOMDriver } from '@cycle/dom';

export default function Counter(sources) {
    const action$ = xs.merge(
        sources.DOM.select('.decrement').events('click').map(ev => -1),
        sources.DOM.select('.increment').events('click').map(ev => +1)
    );

    const state$ = sources.onion.state$;

    const vdom$ = state$.map(state =>
        div([
            button('.decrement', 'Decrement'),
            button('.increment', 'Increment'),
            p('Counter: ' + state.count)
        ])
    );

    const initReducer$ = xs.of(function initReducer() {
        return { count: 0 };
    });
    const updateReducer$ = action$.map(num => function updateReducer(prevState) {
        return { count: prevState.count + num };
    });
    const reducer$ = xs.merge(initReducer$, updateReducer$);

    return {
        DOM: vdom$,
        onion: reducer$,
    };
}
```

### `index.ts`, non-onion main app

```
import xs, { Stream } from 'xstream';
import { run } from '@cycle/run';
import { div, input, h2, button, p, makeDOMDriver, VNode, DOMSource } from '@cycle/dom';

import Counter from "./Counter";
import onionify from 'cycle-onionify';
const counts = onionify(Counter);

interface Sources {
    DOM: DOMSource;
}

interface Sinks {
    DOM: Stream<VNode>;
}

function main(sources: Sources): Sinks {
    const firstName$ = sources.DOM
        .select('.first')
        .events('input')
        .map(ev => (ev.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
        .startWith('');

    const lastName$ = sources.DOM
        .select('.last')
        .events('input')
        .map(ev => (ev.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
        .map(ln => ln.toUpperCase())
        .startWith('');

    const rawFullName$ = xs.combine(firstName$, lastName$)
        .remember();

    const validName$ = rawFullName$
        .filter(([fn, ln]) => fn.length > 0 && ln.length >= 3)
        .map(([fn, ln]) => `${ln.toUpperCase()}, ${fn}`);

    const invalidName$ = rawFullName$
        .filter(([fn, ln]) => fn.length === 0 || ln.length < 3)
        .mapTo('');

    const name$ = xs.merge(validName$, invalidName$);

    const vdom$ = name$.map(name =>
        div([
            p([
                'First name',
                input('.first', { attrs: { type: 'text' } }),
            ]),
            p([
                'Last name',
                input('.last', { attrs: { type: 'text' } }),
            ]),
            h2('Hello ' + name),
        ]),
    );

    return {
        DOM: vdom$,
    };
}

run(main, {
    DOM: makeDOMDriver('#main-container'),
});
```

### Attempts

If I replace `run(main, ...)` with `run(counts, ...)`, as the cycle-onionify docs advise for a fully-onionified app, I see only the counter as expected.

But `counts`, as the output of `onionify(Counter)`, is a function, so I don’t think I can “instantiate” it inside my `main().

Similarly, I don’t think I can create a counter component by calling `Counter()` inside main because that function requires a `sources.onion` input, and I’m not sure how to create that `.onion` field, which has type `StateSource`.

### Question

How exactly can I use this `Counter` onion-ready component inside my non-onionified `main`?

### Full example

Full example is available at https://gist.github.com/fasiha/939ddc22d5af32bd5a00f7d9946ceb39 — clone this, `npm install` to get the requisite packages, then `make` (this runs `tsc` and `browserify` to convert TypeScript→JavaScript→browserified JS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually pretty simple. As you said, you can call `Counter()` in your main, but then it does not have the `StateSource`.

The solution is to replace `Counter()` with `onionify(Counter)()`:

```
function main(sources: Sources): Sinks {
    //other main stuff

    const vdom$ = //implementation here

    const counterSinks = onionify(Counter)(sources);

    const combinedVdom$ = xs.combine(vdom$, counterSinks.DOM)
        .map(div). //Enclose with div

    return {
        DOM: combinedVdom$,
    };
}
```

Note that this will only make use of the DOM sink in the `Counter` so if you want to use other sinks in the counter, you have to specify them as well:

```
const counterSinks = onionify(Counter)(sources);

const combinedVdom$ = xs.combine(vdom$, counterSinks.DOM)
    .map(div). //Enclose with div

return {
    DOM: combinedVdom$,
    HTTP: xs.merge(myOwnRequest$, counterSinks.HTTP)
    //...
};
```

As this is a bit tedious to do this for every sink, I've created a helper in the package `cyclejs-utils`:

```
const counterSinks = onionify(Counter)(sources);

const combinedVdom$ = xs.combine(vdom$, counterSinks.DOM)
    .map(div). //Enclose with div

const ownSinks = { DOM: vdom$, /* ... */ };

return {
    ...mergeSinks(ownSinks, counterSinks)
    DOM: combinedVdom$
};
```

The reason why I specify the DOM extra, is that mergeSinks calls merge on every sink, but for the DOM, you want to use combine + map, to combine the DOM to a new parent DOM exactly how you want to use it.